# Is there a way to scrape from multiple pages on a website but keep my calculated metrics the same in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am new to R and web scraping. For practice, I have been scraping a fake book website ('http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html') and then calculating metrics based on the information that I have scraped. So far, I have managed to calculate the correct metrics for the first page (Mainly thanks to you guys). However, there are 50 pages on this website, all of them include 20 books each. I now want to expand my metric calculations to include all 1000 books on the webpage. By the way, the metrics are:

- Mean length of each individual word in the book titles.
- Most commonly used word including stop words.
- Most commonly used word excluding stop words.
- How many times the word 'and' appears in the book titles.

I have managed to scrape the book title for each page. However, the metrics I have calculated previously now do not work.

Previous Code (one page):

```
url<-paste0('http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html')

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('h3 a') %>%
  html_attr('title')->titles
titles

# Mean lengths of words in book titles:
mean(nchar(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+'))))

# Most used word (Including stop words):
mostUsedWord<-head(sort(table(tolower(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+')))), decreasing = TRUE))[1]
mostUsedWord # 'the' - Used 14 times

# Most used word (excluding stop words)
all_words <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+')))
noStopWords <- head(sort(table(all_words[!all_words %in% tm::stopwords()]), decreasing = TRUE))[1:3]
noStopWords 

# How many times the word 'and' Appears:
word = 'and'
data.frame(word = table(all_words)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(word.all_words == word)
```

Output (List of books):

[1] "A Light in the Attic"
[2] "Tipping the Velvet"
[3] "Soumission"
[4] "Sharp Objects"
[5] "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind"
[6] "The Requiem Red"
[7] "The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job"
[8] "The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull"
[9] "The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics"
[10] "The Black Maria"
[11] "Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade Trilogy, #1)"
[12] "Shakespeare's Sonnets"
[13] "Set Me Free"
[14] "Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)"
[15] "Rip it Up and Start Again"
[16] "Our Band Could Be Your Life: Scenes from the American Indie Underground, 1981-1991"
[17] "Olio"
[18] "Mesaerion: The Best Science Fiction Stories 1800-1849"
[19] "Libertarianism for Beginners"
[20] "It's Only the Himalayas"

The version above outputs the correct values for books on the front page. However, when I attempt to  incorporate all of the pages, the calculation completely mess up, giving errors like: "Error in strsplit(titles, "\s+") : non-character argument" when trying to calculate the mean.

Code for multiple pages:

```
url<-paste0('http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-', 1:50, '.html')

# Scraping the book titles and storing them appropriately:

titles <- purrr::map(
  url,
  . %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes('h3 a') %>%
    html_attr('title')
)
titles

# Mean lengths of words in book titles:
mean(nchar(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+'))))
# Now outputs "Error in strsplit(titles, "\s+") : non-character argument"

# Most used word (Including stop words):
mostUsedWord<-head(sort(table(tolower(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+')))), decreasing = TRUE))[1]
mostUsedWord # Still outputs the initial 1 page value (I want it for all pages)

# Most used word (excluding stop words)
all_words <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+')))
noStopWords <- head(sort(table(all_words[!all_words %in% tm::stopwords()]), decreasing = TRUE))[1:3]
noStopWords # Still outputs the initial 1 page value (I want it for all pages)

# How many times the word 'and' Appears:
word = 'and'
data.frame(word = table(all_words)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(word.all_words == word)
# Still outputs the initial 1 page value (I want it for all pages)
```

Output (List of books):
Same as above but 50 lists of books (1-20)

I would like to know if there is a better way to scrape from all pages on the website that would allow me to calculate the same metrics. Or will I have to completely re-write the code calculating the metrics? In short, I would like to know if there is a way to calculate the above metrics for every single page on the website. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are calcs done on a per page basis?

Comment: I want them to be done as a total for all pages. So how many times the word 'and' is used across all 50 pages etc.

Comment: If you run `titles <-unlist(titles)` first, then you have a single vector with all the titles instead of 50 element list of 20 titles each.